# Verwendung von Artikeln

Tags: grammaticality

Was ist korrekt und warum?

1. Hast du die Geschwister?
2. Hast du Geschwister?
3. Auf dem Himmel fliegen die Vögel?
4. Auf dem Himmel fliegen Vögel?
5. Im Himmel fliegen Vögel.
6. Im Himmel fliegen die Vögel.

Comment: Das sieht wie eine Hausaufgabe aus.

Comment: Das ist keine meine Hausaufgabe. :) Ich bin ein Selbstlerner. Mir ist nichts nur Besseres eingefallen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Man sagt typischerweise

> Hast du Geschwister?

Denn man weiß ja nicht, ob das Gegenüber Geschwister hat. Man würde "die Geschwister" sagen, wenn die Geschwister einem schon bekannt wären (oder wenn über sie schon gesprochen wurde, oder wenn sie sichtbar mit im Raum sind).

Konstruieren wir so einen Fall:

> A: Ich möchte dich zu meinem Geburtstag einladen. Kommst du?
>
> B: Darf ich meine Geschwister und meine Cousins und Cousinen mitbringen?
>
> A: Die Geschwister kannst du gerne mitbringen, aber die Cousins und Cousinen sollten besser zuhause bleiben, wir haben nicht so viel Platz.

Hier sagt A "die Geschwister", nicht weil er sie schon kennt, sondern weil sie schon **Teil der Kommunikation** waren. Sie wurden schon erwähnt. Ihre Existenz wird damit als bekannt vorausgesetzt.

Nun zum nächsten Beispiel:

> Am Himmel fliegen Vögel, im Meer schwimmen Fische, über die Steppe laufen Antilopen.

Das sagst du, wenn es eine ganz allgemeine Feststellung zu typischen Tätigkeiten solcher Tiere ist; oder wenn es darum geht, welche Teile der Landschaft mit welcher Art von Tieren bevölkert sind; wenn es also nicht um konkrete, bereits thematisierte Vögel, Fische, Antilopen geht.

Jedoch stelle dir folgende Situation an: Du schaust mit einem Kind ein Bilderbuch an, in dem Vögel am Himmel, Fische im Meer und Antilopen auf der Steppe abgebildet sind. Ihr habt die Vögel, Fische und Antilopen schon wahrgenommen und vielleicht sogar schon drüber geredet:

> Kuck mal, da sind Fische. Und hier oben, da sind Vögel...

Ab jetzt sind Vögel, Fische und Antilopen euch bereits "bekannt" (sie waren schon Teil der Kommunikation). Darum würdest du von nun an "die" sagen:

> Wo sind die Vögel? Sind die Vögel im Meer? Und wo sind die Antilopen? Fliegen die Antilopen durch den Himmel?

Und das Kind würde sagen:

> Die Fische sind im Wasser.

Aber es kommt eben auf die konkrete Kommunikatkionssituation an. Stell dir vor, du hast das Buch gerade erst aufgeschlagen, ihr habt noch nicht darüber gesprochen, was auf dem Bild zu sehen ist, und du stellst dem Kind die Frage:

> Was fliegt denn da am Himmel?

Dann würde das Kind typischerweise sagen:

> Am Himmel fliegen Vögel.

Interessanterweise hat das Kind ein sehr gutes Gespür dafür, dass über die Vögel (die! denn du und ich, wir haben ja über diese Vögel schon gesprochen) noch nicht gesprochen wurde, darum sagt es "Vögel", nicht "die Vögel".

Comment: Ok. Also wenn, man den Gegenstand kennt, schreibt man immer den bestimmten Artikel? Der Nullartikel schreibt man, wenn etwas für uns unbekannt ist?

Comment: Grundregel: Wenn der Gegenstand bekannt ist (= schon Teil der Kommunikation war) nimmst du bestimmten Artikel. Wenn der Gegenstand neu in der Kommunikation ist, unbestimmten (ein/e) oder Null-Artikel. - Die Sache ist aber leider nicht mit einer so einfachen Regel vollständig zu erhellen. Da du mit einer slavischen Sprache aufgewachsen bist (von denen die meisten eine solche Unterscheidung nicht haben), wirst du sehr viel Zeit und Aufmerksamkeit investieren müssen, um ein Gefühl für die "richtige" (=typische) Verwendung zu entwickeln. Es geht nicht mit einer einfachen Regel.

Comment: Vielleicht noch ein Tip: Leute, die mit slavischen Sprachen aufgewachsen sind, verwenden im Deutschen (und im Englischen) tendenziell zu selten den bestimmten Artikel. Es wäre also eine gute Idee, zu versuchen, es mit dem bestimmten Aritkel lieber etwas zu übertreiben. Du sagst nicht: "Gibst du mir mal Butter" (wenn die Butter sichtbar auf dem Tisch steht), sondern "Gibst du mir mal **die** Butter." - Es fällt weniger auf, wenn zu viele bestimmte Artikel im Satz sind, als wenn es zu wenige sind.

Comment: Es ist etwas komplizierter. Den bestimmten Artikel verwendet man, wenn man von bestimmten Dingen oder Personen spricht (Die Bezeichnung *bestimmter* Artikel kommt nicht von ungefähr). Wenn man die Dinge oder Personen kennt, hat man normalerweise auch diese im Sinn, wenn man davon spricht, und daher sind sie bestimmt. Geht es um unbestimmte Dinge oder Personen, verwendet man in der Einzahl den unbestimmten Artikel (z.B. Hast du einen Bruder?) und in der Mehrzahl - wie hier - den Nullartikel.

Comment: Ja, es ist komplizierter. Wir versuchen nur gerade, es jemandem, der gerade anfängt, sich damit zu beschäftigen, irgendwie halbwegs brauchbar zu erklären...

Comment: Danke Ihre Antwort ist erschöpfend. )

Comment: Meine Antwort bezog sich auf die erste Frage in den Kommentaren, in der Zwischenzeit waren schon weitere Kommentare eingetrudelt.

Comment: :-) Ach so. Ja... jetzt wo du's sagst, erkenne ich, auf was sich das bezog.